# Where to implement an error message in java code

Tags: java

so I am new to Java programming and just a little confused on how to implement an error message. In my code, I would give an error message to show when user enters the limit number below 2, but can't figure it out.

```
package test;  
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class Main
 {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      int limit = 0;
      int sum   = 0;

      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.print("Enter Limit: ");
      limit = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("Sum of the even numbers between 2 and " + limit + " (inclusive) are:");

      for (int count = 1; count <= limit; count++)
      {
        // Needed if ever even

        if((count & 1)!= 1)
        {
            sum+=count;
            System.out.println(count);
        }
      }
      System.out.println("Total sum is " + sum);

 }

}
```

Where would I write my error code? I'm looking for further guidance on where to place an error message, not just in my code but for future reference as well. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe some code like

```
while (limit < 2) {
    System.out.print("Enter Limit: ");
    limit = scan.nextInt();
}
```

If you want some extra `message` if the input is incorrect then introduce a boolean value

```
boolean firstTime = true;
while (limit < 2) {
    if (!firstTime) {
       System.out.println ("Enter Below 2 ");
    }
    System.out.print("Enter Limit: ");
    limit = scan.nextInt();
    firstTime = false;
}
```

Comment: Since you have to enter the loop anyway, I would, personally, use a `do-while`, but that's me :P

Comment: @user10650011 If this works for you please consider to upvote and/or accept this answer

Answer (score 1):

Add

```
while (limit < 2) {
    System.out.println("Limit must be >= 2");  // this is your error message
    System.out.print("Enter Limit: ");
    limit = scan.nextInt();
}
```

after

```
System.out.print("Enter Limit: ");
limit = scan.nextInt();
```

Comment: this works as well and little easier to comprehend, thank you!